# Exception raised when running ipython notebook

Tags: exception, handler, fedora, jupyter-notebook, julia

I used to have ipython notebook working correctly in fedora, but then tried to get ipython notebook for julia with Pkg.build("IJulia") and Pkg.add("IJulia").
After doing this and updating my ipython version with pip I could not run ipython notebook anymore, the next exception was raised over and over again:

```
ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 346, in start
    self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
KeyError: 6
^C2014-08-12 22:51:35.024 [NotebookApp] CRITICAL | received signal 2, stopping
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which version of `pyzmq` is installed on your system?

Comment: I'm on Fedora 19 and did `yum erase python-zmq` and then `pip install pyzmq` to get it to work with the latest Julia.  I also run `pip install -U ipython sphinx pip sphinx-rtd-theme setuptools tornado pyzmq` on occasion to keep everything current.  N.B.  There's probably a better way by using [Python Virtual Environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Comment: I don't know which version is installed :S, but did it with pip so think good one

Comment: tried `yum erase python-zmq` and `pip install pyzmq` then not even ipython would run. Tried `pip install -U ipython sphinx pip sphinx-rtd-theme setuptools tornado pyzmq`and got same error :S.

Comment: Well the issue was solved by installing anaconda, don't know what the problem was but I would recommend installing it if someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting `IJulia` to work is lot easier now, `Pkg.add("IJulia")` will search for `jupyter` or `ipython` in `PATH`, if not found it will use [Conda.jl](https://github.com/Luthaf/Conda.jl) to install the dependencies. Another option which was tried successfully by the OP is to separately install `Jupyter`(which comes along `Anaconda`) to system path, and then install `IJulia`. Then should be able to open the notebooks by,

```
julia>using IJulia
julia>notebook
```

Alternatively you can open a notebook by running `jupyter notebook` in the command line.

PS : Credits to OP and commenters.